# Using vtkCamera explicit projection transform matrix and prop3D visibility

Tags: python, vtk

Essentially, I want to employ VTK-engine to render a scene with both precalculated projection and model view transform matrices, together called as "composite projection transform matrix".

For such purpose, we have `vtkCamera.SetUseExplicitProjectionTransformMatrix` but I cannot make my view props or actors visible using that. I guess it is related to how the `vtkRenderer` pre-selects visible actor by using their bounding boxes, but in this case near and far clipping ranges are baked into a single matrix, so the renderer cannot even guess that. In the below sample code I also compensate camera's initial modelviewtransform matrix (which is slightly translated from identity matrix), so that the camera would calculate its composite projection the way I want.

```
import vtk

class Renderer:
    def __init__( self ):
        self.layer0 = vtk.vtkRenderer()
        self.layer0.SetLayer(0)
        self.renWin = vtk.vtkRenderWindow()
        self.renWin.AddRenderer(self.layer0)
        self.iren = vtk.vtkRenderWindowInteractor()
        self.iren.SetRenderWindow(self.renWin)
        self.iren.Initialize()      
    def Render( self ):
        self.iren.Render()
    def AddActor( self, actor ):
        self.layer0.AddActor( actor )
    def Start(self):
        self.iren.Start()

def CreateActor( polydata ):
    mapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
    mapper.SetInputData( polydata )
    mapper.SetScalarVisibility( 0 )
    actor = vtk.vtkActor()
    actor.SetMapper( mapper )
    return actor

def OBJReader( name ):
    reader = vtk.vtkOBJReader()
    reader.SetFileName( name )
    reader.Update()
    return reader.GetOutput()

# Suzanne by Blender.org
suzanne = OBJReader( 'D:/data/suzanne.obj' )

size = (900,600)

# Create a VTK renderwindow
r = Renderer()
r.renWin.SetSize(size[0],size[1])
r.AddActor( CreateActor(suzanne) )
# Use vtkRenderWindowInteractor to select the camera view
# Then exit the window by pressing 'x'
r.Start()

# Store the current composite projection transform matrix
# i.e., the product of the projection and the modelview matrix
# into X
c = r.layer0.GetActiveCamera()
n, f = c.GetClippingRange()
aspect = size[0]/size[1]
X = c.GetCompositeProjectionTransformMatrix( aspect, n, f )

# Create another VTK renderwindow
r2 = Renderer()
r2.renWin.SetSize(size[0],size[1])
r2.AddActor( CreateActor(suzanne) )

# but this time, construct the camera by using a precomputed
# projection matrix
c2 = vtk.vtkCamera()
if 1:
    # assert that the modelview matrix will be identity matrix
    M = vtk.vtkMatrix4x4()
    M.DeepCopy( c2.GetModelViewTransformMatrix() )
    print( M ) # its not!
    M.Invert() # so invert
    # and concatenate
    Y = vtk.vtkMatrix4x4()
    # Y*M = X*inv(M)*M = X
    vtk.vtkMatrix4x4.Multiply4x4( X, M, Y )

    c2.SetUseExplicitProjectionTransformMatrix(1)
    c2.SetExplicitProjectionTransformMatrix( Y )

    # these should be now the same (in case of explicit, aspect, n and f are ignored)
    print( c2.GetCompositeProjectionTransformMatrix( 1, 0, 0 ) )
    print( X )


else:
    #this works clearly
    c2.DeepCopy( c )

r2.layer0.SetActiveCamera( c2 )
r2.Render()
r2.Start()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After testing, I came to conclusion that one is supposed to use `vtkExternalOpenGLCamera`

> This class extends vtkOpenGLCamera by introducing API wherein the
>   camera matrices can be set explicitly by the application.

The composite projection transform matrix `X` is not readily usable though, but it's clipping range must be changed s.t.

```
# copy X into numpy matrix for comfort
P = np.zeros( (4,4),dtype=np.double)
for y in range(4):
    for x in range(4):
        P[y][x]=X.GetElement(y,x)
# P maps valid z-values to [n,f] so change that by
# z <- 2.0 * ( z - n )/(f-n) -1.0
# to fit values into the default clipping range [-1,1]
A = np.eye(4,dtype=np.double)
A[2][3]=-n
B = np.eye(4, dtype=np.double)
B[2][2]=2.0/(f-n)
C = np.eye(4, dtype=np.double)
C[2][3]=-1.0
P = np.matmul(C,np.matmul(B,np.matmul(A,P)) )

# then use vtkExternalOpenGLCamera
c2 = vtk.vtkExternalOpenGLCamera()
c2.SetViewTransformMatrix( np.reshape( np.eye(4,dtype=np.double),[-1,1]) )
c2.SetProjectionTransformMatrix( np.reshape( np.transpose(P),[-1,1]) )
r2.layer0.SetActiveCamera( c2 )
r2.Render()
```

Worth noting, that the matrix `P` below also works with modelview matrix transform hack mentioned above:

```
c2 = vtk.vtkCamera()

# P is now back to vtk.vtkMatrix4x4 type

# assert that the modelview matrix will be identity matrix
Mx = vtk.vtkMatrix4x4()
Mx.DeepCopy( c2.GetModelViewTransformMatrix() )
print( Mx ) # its not!
Mx.Invert() # so invert
# Y*M = X*inv(M)*M = X
vtk.vtkMatrix4x4.Multiply4x4( P, Mx, P )

c2.SetUseExplicitProjectionTransformMatrix(1)
c2.SetExplicitProjectionTransformMatrix( P )
```

but the result is not pretty...

Although the default camera light model of VTK does not work with the baked composite transform, it does work if the projection and model view matrices are put separately into the `vtkExternalOpenGLCamera`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the problem because the code seems to work fine with a mesh I have..

Maybe try adding `c.ResetCameraClippingRange()` somewhere might help.

Also consider using the [vtkplotter](https://github.com/marcomusy/vtkplotter) helper module to easily create/load vtk objects. E.g.:

```py
from vtkplotter import *

vp = Plotter()
suzanne = load('D:/data/suzanne.obj') # returns a vtkActor
print(vp.camera.GetModelViewTransformMatrix())
vp.show(suzanne, resetcam=False)
```

Comment: Granted, vtkplotter makes rendering much concise, however, the default VTK rendering engine does not allow modification of the projection matrix directly, but rather via `SetViewAngle` and so on. The `r2` renderer in my sample tries to demonstrate that, although in the example just by copying matrices from `r`